# one commit two branches two different files

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have the same commit in the history of the two branches, but some files in the commit have different content:
[image: compare source file of two different branches]

How is that possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have some questions about your problem. 1) Are you sure that's the same file? 2) That doesn't look like a recent BitBucket screenshot, [for example](https://bitbucket.org/fenics-project/ufl/src/250f1834737b/ufl/functionspace.py?at=cecile%2Fmixed-dimensional&fileviewer=file-view-default). Where is it coming from? 3) Tools are sometimes wrong. Verify with Git. What do `git log -p 50a3441da99` and `git show 50a3441da99:<thatfile>` say?

Comment: Beware of your wording, though, because *two branches pointing at the same commit* and *two branches having the same commit in their history* are WAY different things. And you seem to refer to the former case while using the latter expression.